# Debugging FullCalendar to Google Calendar integration

Tags: fullcalendar

I was asked to implement FullCalendar for our company's web application to pull in a calendar from Google Calendar. I have imported and referenced the JS and CSS files to where I am getting the calendar to appear to appear on the page configured the way that we want, however, there no events showing up.

I saw on the FullCalendar site a note, "If you need to detect errors with the Google API ... You'll need to use the FullCalendar's googleCalendarError callback ..."  But there was no examples and no documentation on how to perform this. I Googled for examples and found no code examples of how to do this so that I could debug what was happening and why the calendar appears structurally, but with no calendar data.  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**Update:** After playing with the gcal.html demo example that comes with FullCalendar, I was able to get my calendar to work and show event information in gcal.html.  However, in my MVC .net application there is a JS error stating "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()" and it shows my MVC view page address on my local machine appended with the google calendar id, along with start and end dates. I am wondering where I go from here to get my calendar to appear in my MVC .net web application view page and pull event information from Google.

Comment: I deleted my answer since it was an educated guess and didn't work. Good luck